# RNNLM using theano

Tags: python, nlp, theano, recurrent-neural-network, language-model

I asked the same question on theano user list, but got no reply, just wondering if anyone can help me here.

I am trying to re-implement the RNNLM of http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/research/groups/speech/publi/2010/mikolov_interspeech2010_IS100722.pdf based on this nice post.
I tried a toy test case which training data is the first 100 sentences of PTB training data (downloaded from http://rnnlm.org/ ), the same data also used for evaluation.

**Baseline:**

I trained the LM with 25 iterations, using rnnlm-0.4b from http://rnnlm.org/, I got
test log probability: -4107.323481
PPL net: 85.496622

The command lines that to produce the baseline are:

```
$ rnnlm -train ../ptb/ptb.train.txt.toy -valid ../ptb/ptb.train.txt.toy -rnnlm rnn.model.toy -hidden 10 -class 1 -max-iter 25 -independent -beta 0 -direct-order 0
$ rnnlm -rnnlm rnn.model.toy -test ../ptb/ptb.train.txt.toy -independent
```

**Using my implementation**, after 25 iterations, there is a large difference in PPL:

> epoch=24: log probability=-5374.255371 ppl=337.187731

I am still learning Theano, did i miss something in my implementation?

Thanks

My implementation can be found at [here](https://11350770138305416713.googlegroups.com/attach/179c4942cbf157/rnnlm.py?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrGZjtk4NfhfR2gY8Xk3x5yDxT5FUczkzSB6PRIGVu7lN_Dr9XHUZcYNE3WSrEc6SCL7vf8O9Xg5oCuzST4Z5oxo0WgCAIjBz7X0SC_4ZnvpsKf4HII):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import itertools
import codecs
import numpy as np
import nltk
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime
import theano as theano
import theano.tensor as T

class RNNLM:

    def __init__(self, word_dim, hidden_dim=100, bptt_truncate=4):
        # Assign instance variables
        self.word_dim = word_dim
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.bptt_truncate = bptt_truncate
        # Randomly initialize the network parameters
        U = np.random.uniform(-np.sqrt(1./word_dim), np.sqrt(1./word_dim), (hidden_dim, word_dim))
        V = np.random.uniform(-np.sqrt(1./hidden_dim), np.sqrt(1./hidden_dim), (word_dim, hidden_dim))
        W = np.random.uniform(-np.sqrt(1./hidden_dim), np.sqrt(1./hidden_dim), (hidden_dim, hidden_dim))
        # Theano: Created shared variables
        self.U = theano.shared(name='U', value=U.astype(theano.config.floatX))  # @UndefinedVariable
        self.V = theano.shared(name='V', value=V.astype(theano.config.floatX))  # @UndefinedVariable
        self.W = theano.shared(name='W', value=W.astype(theano.config.floatX))      # @UndefinedVariable
        # We store the Theano graph here
        self.theano = {}
        self.__theano_build__()

    def __theano_build__(self):
        U, V, W = self.U, self.V, self.W
        x = T.ivector('x')
        y = T.ivector('y')
        def forward_prop_step(x_t, s_t_prev, U, V, W):
            s_t = T.tanh(U[:,x_t] + W.dot(s_t_prev))
            o_t = V.dot(s_t)

            return [o_t, s_t]
        [o,s], updates = theano.scan(
            forward_prop_step,
            sequences=x,
            outputs_info=[None, dict(initial=T.zeros(self.hidden_dim))],
            non_sequences=[U, V, W],
            truncate_gradient=self.bptt_truncate,
            strict=True)
        p_x_given_h = T.nnet.softmax(o)

        o_error = T.sum(T.nnet.categorical_crossentropy(p_x_given_h, y))
        logp = T.sum(T.log10(p_x_given_h)[T.arange(y.shape[0]), y])


        # Gradients
        dU = T.grad(o_error, U)
        dV = T.grad(o_error, V)
        dW = T.grad(o_error, W)

        # Assign functions
        self.forward_propagation = theano.function([x], p_x_given_h)
        self.ce_error = theano.function([x, y], o_error)
        self.logp = theano.function([x, y], logp)
        # SGD
        learning_rate = T.scalar('learning_rate')
        self.sgd_step = theano.function([x,y,learning_rate], [], 
                      updates=[(self.U, self.U - learning_rate * dU),
                              (self.V, self.V - learning_rate * dV),
                              (self.W, self.W - learning_rate * dW)])

    def calculate_total_loss(self, X, Y):
        return np.sum([self.ce_error(x,y) for x,y in zip(X,Y)])

    def calculate_loss(self, X, Y):
        # Divide calculate_loss by the number of words
        num_words = np.sum([len(y) for y in Y])
        return self.calculate_total_loss(X,Y)/float(num_words)   

    def calculate_ppl(self, X, Y):
        num_words = np.sum([len(y) for y in Y])
        #print "word count: " + str(num_words)
        logp = np.sum([self.logp(x,y) for x,y in zip(X,Y)])
        ppl = 10 ** (-logp/num_words)
        return ppl, logp


def train_with_sgd(model, X_train, y_train, X_valid, y_valid, learning_rate=0.005, nepoch=1, evaluate_loss_after=5):
    # We keep track of the losses so we can plot them later
    losses = []
    num_examples_seen = 0
    for epoch in range(nepoch):
        # For each training example...
        for i in range(len(y_train)):
            model.sgd_step(X_train[i], y_train[i], learning_rate)
            num_examples_seen += 1

        loss = model.calculate_loss(X_train, y_train)
        losses.append((num_examples_seen, loss))
        time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')

        loss = model.calculate_loss(X_valid, y_valid)
        ppl, logp = model.calculate_ppl(X_valid, y_valid)

        print "epoch=%d: log probability=%f ppl=%f" % (epoch,logp,ppl)
        # Adjust the learning rate if loss increases
        if (len(losses) > 1 and losses[-1][1] > losses[-2][1]):
            learning_rate = learning_rate * 0.5  
            print "Setting learning rate to %f" % learning_rate

def load_data():
    print "load data..."

    train = [("%s %s %s" % (sentence_end_token, x.strip(), sentence_end_token)).split() for x in codecs.open("../ptb/ptb.train.txt.toy", "r", "UTF-8")]

    print "Parsed %d sentences." % (len(train))

    # Count the word frequencies
    word_freq = nltk.FreqDist(itertools.chain(*train))
    print "Found %d unique words tokens." % len(word_freq.items())

    vocab = word_freq.most_common()
    index_to_word = [x[0] for x in vocab]
    word_to_index = dict([(w,i) for i,w in enumerate(index_to_word)])

    X_train = np.asarray([[word_to_index[w] for w in sent[:-1]] for sent in train])
    y_train = np.asarray([[word_to_index[w] for w in sent[1:]] for sent in train])


    vocabulary_size = len(word_to_index)

    return  X_train, y_train, vocabulary_size + 1 



hidden_dim = 10
sentence_end_token = "eos"
learning_rate = 0.1
nepoc=25
bptt_truncate=100
model_file=None

# Read the data 
X_train, y_train, vocabulary_size = load_data()
print "vocabulary_size: " + str(vocabulary_size)
model = RNNLM(vocabulary_size, hidden_dim=hidden_dim)
train_with_sgd(model, X_train, y_train, X_train, y_train, nepoch=nepoc, learning_rate=learning_rate)
```

Comment: I think it might be how you have initialized your parameters. In RNNLM implementation `rnnlm.cpp` line 33 onwards lists the parameter values. Line 112, default size of hidden layer is 30, while you have initialized yours to be 10. Can you comment you code more and we can help you to debug the problem better? There's some weird notation such as `bptt_truncate` that is not so conventional. Usually, bptt properties are "amount of steps to propagate error back in time" (I would call it `bptt_step`)

Comment: or or `bptt_block` that "specifies amount of time steps after which the error is backpropagated through time in block mode". There are also other things that you've missed like the L2 regularizer parameter. RNNLM also have some intricate things like "Setting maximal absolute gradient value" and "Setting the minimal relative entropy improvement for training convergence"

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same problem. I'm not sure I've found all the problems but if you print out the V weights you'll find them much larger than the others. I divided by the vocabulary size instead of number of hidden weights. It's helping but the net still doesn't converge all the way.

You'll want to print the values for all the weights, this code will get you started.

I tried adding L1 and L2 regularization, it didn't help.

```
V = np.random.uniform(-np.sqrt(1./n_unique_words), np.sqrt(1./n_unique_words), (n_unique_words, n_hidden))

def sum_weights(self):
    v = self.V.sum()
    return v.eval()

def abs_sum_weights(self):
    v = (np.abs(self.V)).sum()
    return v.eval()
```

This is still a work in progress. I don't think you need more than the snippets I gave you. If you do the rest is here. https://github.com/timestocome/AliceInWonderland If you walk back a few updates you'll find the L1/L2 code.